# Why is my table not automatically created at the time of custom module install?

Tags: 7, forms, database

I am writing a custom module for Drupal 7. For the table creation I have created the .install file, but the table is not getting created automatically, when the module is installed. I have already uninstalled and reinstalled the module many times. All the times I do it, I get the following error:

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'drupal.drupalform' doesn't exist

This is the code in the drupalform.install file.

```
function drupalform_schema() {
    $schema = array();
    $schema['drupalform'] = array(
        'description' => t('A table for holding the drupalform data!'),
        'fields' => array(
            'id' => array(
                'description' => t('Auto increment of the ID'),
                'type' => 'serial',
                'unsigned' => TRUE,
                'not null' => TRUE,
            ),
            'name' => array(
                'description' => t('Person\'s first name.'),
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 64,
                'not null' => TRUE,
            ),
            'last_name' => array(
                'description' => t('Person\'s last name.'),
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 64,
                'not null' => TRUE,
            ),
            'email' => array(
                'description' => t('Person\'s email'),
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 64,
                'not null' => TRUE
            ),
        ),
        'primary key' => array('id'),
    );
    return $schema;
}

function drupalform_install() {
    drupal_install_schema('drupalform');
}

function drupalform_uninstall() {
    drupal_uninstall_schema('drupalform');
}
```

Comment: Have you definitely uninstalled it and re-installed it, or just disabled and re-enabled? Assuming your module is named `drupalform`, that code is fine

Comment: The module was uninstalled and reinstalled.

Comment: Verify whether any error is getting logged (recent log messages) while you are installing your module.

Comment: It is showing two messages:

1). 1 orphaned actions (registration_views_set_state_action) exist in the actions table. Remove orphaned actions.

2). drupalform module enabled.

Comment: declare primary key like below,
'code' 'primary key' = array('id'),
and remove drupal_install_schema('drupalform'); from your hook_install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line is not correct.

```
'primary_key' => array('id'),
```

Replace `'primary_key'` with `'primary key'`.

In Drupal 7 you do not need to call `drupal_install_schema()` nor `drupal_uninstall_schema()` for the database tables your module uses.

You can just declare the functions.

```
function drupalform_install() {}

function drupalform_uninstall() {}
```

Just update the code, uninstall the module, and re-install it.

Comment: It was 'primary key' before not 'primary_key'. By the way. it is also not working.

I already removed the:
unction drupalform_install() { drupal_install_schema('drupalform'); }

function drupalform_uninstall() { drupal_uninstall_schema('drupalform'); }

Comment: What is the error message you get now. Have you uninstall the module and reinstall it or only disable and enable it.

Comment: I am installing the module not enable or disable.

Recent log is showing two messages:
 1). 1 orphaned actions (registration_views_set_state_action) exist in the actions table. Remove orphaned actions. 2). drupalform module enabled.

Comment: Could it be phpmyadmin issue?

Comment: There is no issue code. Some other issue. I am able to create table using your code.